# How to filter null values in select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
DataTable:
 id int,
 user_id int,
 field_id int,
 value varchar
```

DataExample:

```
id    user_id    field_id   value 
 1       1            1       'Peter'
 2       1            2       56
 3       1            3       100
 4       2            1       'Buzz'
 5       2            2       47
 6       2            3       120
 7       3            1       'Wolf'
 8       3            2        null
 9       3            3        null
```

I want to separate value column by `field_id` property:

```
Name    Age     Score
Peter   56      100
Buzz    47      120
```

I do:

```
SELECT id, MAX(Name) AS Name, MAX(Age) AS Age, MAX(Score) AS Score
FROM (
SELECT u.id
 CASE
   WHEN field_id = 1 THEN  value
 END as Name,   
 CASE
    WHEN field_id = 2 THEN  value
 END as Age,
 CASE
   WHEN field_id = 3 THEN  value
 END as Score
 FROM Users u
 INNER JOIN DataTable t ON (t.user_id=u.id)
 ) AS sub
GROUP BY id;
```

It's works nice. But now i want to filter null values. I mean i dont want to select rows with `Age` or `Score` = `null`. I tried add `is not null` in CASE blocks but it not helped.
Any advises?

Comment: try `ifnull()`. Check it out.

Comment: Why in CASE blocks? Do you forget about `WHERE`?

Comment: Could you please add row with NULL to data example and show how it will impact output?

Comment: They are probably really not null and just a blank space.

Comment: Added example with nulls

Comment: So what do you want for Wolf? No row at all?

Comment: Yeah i dont want to see Wolf. Update example - delete Wolf from expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a double self-join:

```
select t1.value as name, t2.value as Age, t3.value as Score
from (select userid, value from DataTable where field_id = 1) as t1
join (select userid, value from DataTable where field_id = 2) as t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
join (select userid, value from DataTable where field_id = 3) as t3 ON t1.userid = t3.userid
```

The first sub-query returns names, the second returns ages, and the third scores.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, MAX(Name) AS Name, MAX(Age) AS Age, MAX(Score) AS Score
FROM (
SELECT u.id
 CASE
   WHEN field_id = 1 THEN  value
 END as Name,   
 CASE
    WHEN field_id = 2 THEN  value
 END as Age,
 CASE
   WHEN field_id = 3 THEN  value
 END as Score
 FROM Users u
 INNER JOIN DataTable t ON (t.user_id=u.id)
   WHERE value IS NOT NULL -------------------here
 ) AS sub
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Im still got a null values,

Comment: then check whether that field is a blank rather than a NULL